# Matlab while loop troubleshooting

Tags: matlab

I'm new to use Matlab and need some help to fix this while loop.
I can't get the while loop to work. I want the loop to continue until the variable Velocity2 is >= -20 but the code doesn't stop running.

**Functions**

```
function [a] = acceleration(F,m,g) a=(F-m*g)/m;

function [v] = velocity(a,t,v0,t0) v=v0+a*(t-t0);

function [h] = height(a,t,h0,v0,t0) h=h0+v0*(t-t0)+(1/2)*a*(t-t0).^2;
```

**Code**

```
t0=0.15; % Initial time

dt=0.001; % Timesteps/Precision

v0=46.5285; % Initial velocity

h0=3.4896% Initial height

m=0.05; %Mass

g=9.81; % The gravitational constant

Velocity2=v0;

while Velocity2>=-20

 t=t0+dt;
 Velocity2=velocity(acceleration(0,m,g),t,v0,t0);
 Height2=height(acceleration(0,m,g),t,h0,v0,t0);

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the time isn't changing: `t=t0+dt;` will always turn the same value for `t` which will also prevent Velocity2 from getting lower and therefore always remain above -20, which will cause an infinite loop.
Changing `t=t0+dt;` to `t=t+dt;` should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
t = t0

while Velocity2>=-20
    Velocity2=velocity(acceleration(0,m,g),t,v0,t0);
    Height2=height(acceleration(0,m,g),t,h0,v0,t0);

    t = t + dt;
end
```